# Android: Adapter Changed outside ListView Issue

Tags: java, android, listview

I am trying to build an Address Searcher using Geocoder API where the user types in names of locations and all the related addresses appear in a listview.

**I get this error when running the search:**

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: The content of the adapter has
>   changed but ListView did not receive a notification. Make sure the
>   content of your adapter is not modified from a background thread, but
>   only from the UI thread.
>
> Make sure your adapter calls
>   notifyDataSetChanged() when its content changes.

**This is my implementation:**

```
SimpleStringAdapter adapter;
ArrayList<String> items = new ArrayList<>();
ListView addressList;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_search_address); 

    addressList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.addressList);
    addressBox = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.addressBox);

    //Search for locations when the user types in
    addressBox.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(final CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                //Search the typed location
                SearchAddresses(searchText);
            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                                          int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            }
    });
}

private void SearchAddresses(String searchText) {
    Geocoder geoCoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
    try {
        List<Address> addresses = geoCoder.getFromLocationName(searchText, 5);
        addressList.setAdapter(null);

        if (addresses.size() != 0) {
            //Add the Address line to the list
            items.add(addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0));
            //Populate the listview
            adapter = new SimpleStringAdapter(this, items);
            addressList.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

And the ListView Adapter simply just sets the text to a TextView. If you need to see it, let me know.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: apply notifydatasetchanged to the your adapter.

Comment: Please tell me where to add that in regard to the code sample @LoveAndroid

Comment: I've seen a few answers that say the same thing but none of them state where I should add it and any explanations :)

Comment: Not the best place to initialize adapter. Move this code to onCreate  adapter = new SimpleStringAdapter(this, items);
addressList.setAdapter(adapter);

You are creating a new adapter each time SearchAddress is called.
call adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()  in seachAddress after you add items to the list..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't initialize adapter everytime in onTextChanged() method. use notifyDataSetChanged(). here is example with your code.

Just Replace your code with this. That's it.

```
SimpleStringAdapter adapter;
ArrayList<String> items = new ArrayList<>();
ListView addressList;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_search_address); 

    addressList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.addressList);
    addressBox = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.addressBox);

    adapter = new SimpleStringAdapter(this, items);
    addressList.setAdapter(adapter);

    //Search for locations when the user types in
    addressBox.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(final CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                //Search the typed location
                SearchAddresses(searchText);
            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                                      int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            }
    });
}

private void SearchAddresses(String searchText) {
    Geocoder geoCoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
    try {
        List<Address> addresses =     geoCoder.getFromLocationName(searchText, 5);
        addressList.setAdapter(null);

        if (addresses.size() != 0) {
            //Add the Address line to the list
            items.add(addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0));
            //Populate the listview
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't show any results in the listview. Is it correct?

Comment: yes it is definitely correct. It should work.  

ok ok, I got the problem.

Remove this line from SearchAddresses : addressList.setAdapter(null);

and now try.

Comment: That seems to work but I have a small issue. There is a slight and obvious lag when typing. Is it because multiple requests are sent to the SearchAddresses method?

Comment: Yes this is because of every character notifying adapter.
Google Place API is the best solution for this.
Try [Google Place API](https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/autocomplete)

Answer (score 1):

Try this adding the notifyDataSetChanged to the adapter :-

```
    private void SearchAddresses(String searchText) {
    Geocoder geoCoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
    try {
        List<Address> addresses = geoCoder.getFromLocationName(searchText, 5);
        addressList.setAdapter(null);

        if (addresses.size() != 0) {
            //Add the Address line to the list
            items.add(addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0));
            //Populate the listview
            adapter = new SimpleStringAdapter(this, items);
            addressList.setAdapter(adapter);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: This works but I am seeing a slight lag. I think it's partly because the adapter is initialised every time the text changes

Comment: @DinukaJayasuriya Yup ! you are right . it is happening because adapter is initialised every time the text changes.